# How to push-forward second derivative of the curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pushforward

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a curve on, say, $\mathbb R^3$. Then $\alpha'(t)_{\alpha(t)}$ is a vector(arrow) from $\alpha$ to $\alpha + \alpha'$.

For a vector field $F:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$,its derivative-version $F_*:T_p(\mathbb R^3)\to T_p(\mathbb R^3)$ is a function of tangent vector field such that $F_*(\alpha'(t))=\beta'(t)$ while $\beta(t)=F(\alpha(t))$.

Then What is the function that works with the second derivative?    $G_* : T_p(\mathbb R^3)\to T_p(\mathbb R^3)$ such that $G_*(\alpha'')=\beta''$?
Would $F_*$ work?

Comment: Push-forward and pull-back are to do with differential inclusion. This means that a parametric curve can be real from the origin to the surface of the manifold, provided that your attributes follow a separation function of $ k $ defined by the map between the topology and the kernel.

Comment: The answer is that there is none. The second derivative is tensorial only at a critical point. Try differentiating $F\circ\alpha$ twice.